# Using 'background-size: 100%'

Tags: html, css, background, resize, fixed

So I am trying to use a background image in the bottom left of my page but I want it fixed and to resize with the browser window.

The only way I get close at all to reaching this goal is using 'background-size: 100%' However, that then makes the image TOO tall. So I'm not sure what to use to actually make it fit.

Any suggestions?

This is my current code...

```
body {
background-color:#000000;
background-image:url(Image.png);
background-position: 0% 100%;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, `background-size` takes more than [just one value](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp).  You could try something like this:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

However, for simplicity, first try:

```
background-size: cover;
```

This would make the width of the background automatically adjust to the aspect ratio of the `100%` height.  This guarantees that the background image will never be smaller or larger than the height, but the width is variable to the aspect ratio of their browser.

**ADDENDUM**

Also note that `background-size` is not supported in all browsers.  If support for Internet Explorer is an issue for you, then I'd strongly suggest a Javascript fall-back.  I'd also **highly** suggest reading the always lovely Chris Coyier's article on the ["Perfect Full Page Background Image"](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/).  It discusses fallbacks of all kinds!

Comment: @MelissaMae: Please, check out the addendum I added to this, I feel you may find it of greater help than "just finding **a** solution".